# Javascript or Jquery Math Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use these JavaScript  or jquery math functions ?

For example, I want to compute the sum of all  values in a form, without submiting the form or in button click.
I have 4 input fields and i want to add then and put the result of them in another input or paragraph.
Html code looks like this :

```
<form id='myform'>
    <label> Number 1 : </label><input value="" id="1"/><br>
    <label> Number 2 : </label><input value="" id="2"/><br>
    <label> Number 3 : </label><input value="" id="3"/><br>
    <label> Number 4 : </label><input value="" id="4"/><br> <br>
    <button href="#" class='add'> ADD</button> 
    <p id="p"> </p>
</form>
```

I tried  to do something like this :

```
var one   = $("#1").val();
var two   = $("#2").val(); 
var three = $("#3").val();
var four  = $("#4").val(); 
$("add").on("click", function(){
    var sum = one + two + three + four;
    $('p').text(sum);        
})
```

I created a `jsfiddle`: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/fs5ysde1/14/)
Can you give a little help? Thank you.

Comment: Fetch input value inside click handler https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/LcyazLn1/

Comment: Always use document-ready handler, see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Satpal - no need for the document ready handler in that link.  It's running `onLoad` as per jsfiddle defaults.

Comment: @Archer, You just can't really on fiddle `Onload` or `onDomReady` as I have seen questions like code running in fiddle but not in site etc

Comment: @Satpal So have I, so you should have disabled the fiddle event handlers to avoid possible confusion.  Anyway, I see no mention from the OP of the code not running.  Is he not using document ready handlers then?

Comment: @Archer, OP has started using jQuery and learning its always better to introduce him/her to good practices. Anyways its upto you.

Comment: @Satpal - No.  Ask first and then answer, or you confuse the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this...

```
$(".add").on("click", function(){
    var one   = parseInt($("#1").val(), 10);
    var two   = parseInt($("#2").val(), 10); 
    var three = parseInt($("#3").val(), 10);
    var four  = parseInt($("#4").val(), 10); 
    var sum = one + two + three + four;
    $("p").text(sum);        // or $("#p") since you gave it an ID
});
```

That way you get the values at the time you click "add", and you also need `parseInt()` to convert the values into integers, or they'll be treated as strings and concatenated instead.

Incidentally, using numbers as element IDs is not recommended.  Simply prefixing them with a common name would be a good idea, like `#value1`, `#value2` etc..

There was also a small issues with your markup, which I fixed...

```
<form id='myform'>
    <label> Number 1 : </label><input value="" id="1"/><br>
    <label> Number 2 : </label><input value="" id="2"/><br>
    <label> Number 3 : </label><input value="" id="3"/><br>
    <label> Number 4 : </label><input value="" id="4"/><br> <br>
    <button type="button" class="add">ADD</button> 
    <p id="p"> </p>
</form>
```

The `button` element defaults to a submit button, unless you specify `type="button"`, so it was causing the page to submit, rather than just handle the button click.  You can stop this with the click event handler, but I prefer to set the button type.

Here's the working example...

https://jsfiddle.net/fs5ysde1/17/

Comment: `$(".add")` missed `.` also and add few line for document-ready handler

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about the `.` - I didn't spot that.  I'm not adding a document ready handler though as that's out of scope of the question and assuming the OP doesn't already have one.

Comment: @archer  I run your code. It seems its not working in jsfiddle. Could you check it please

Comment: @Archer you'll also need to cancel the `click` event, otherwise it'll trigger a form submission. The event object is the first argument passed to the handler, so grab that and call `.preventDefault()` on it, or just return `false` from the handler.

Comment: I've updated it and added a working example for you to see.  Also, if relevant, do pay attention to what @Satpal said about the document ready handler.

Comment: @KevinNagurski I've handled that, thanks.  No need for extra code - just an extra attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add `+` before each to covert it into number if you want to add it as a  number like this `+$("#1").val();`

```
$(".add").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var one   = +$("#1").val();
        var two   = +$("#2").val(); 
        var three = +$("#3").val();
        var four  = +$("#4").val(); 
        var sum = one + two + three + four;
        $('#p').text(sum);        
    })
```

Comment: `$(".add")` missed `.` also, Just code dump is not use full

Answer (score 0):

I know we have our answer, but I thought I'd show a different approach :-)

```
// get all the fields in one go
var $fields = $('#myform input');

$('.add').click(function(e){
    // kill the form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    var total = 0;
    $fields.each(function(pos, el) {
        // get the the vals, and, if blank, default to 0
        total += parseInt($(el).val()) || 0;
    });

    $('p').text(total);
});
```